# RMI, EJB and callback

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, rmi, callback

Is it possible for a client to pass an RMI object as an argument to an EJB so that the 
EJB may callback the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to pass the connection details in the call to the EJB and have the EJB make a connection to the client-side RMI server.

My advise would be to use messaging and a temporary queue for the asynchronous behaviour it sounds like you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

No.  Remote objects cannot be serialized and moved to other locations, since the connection to the remote object itself is transient in nature.

It may be possible to use some kind wrapper object that can be serialized and will reestablish the RMI connection once sent to the EJB.